# receiving android push notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've got my registartion ID of my device, and when I'm trying to send push notification from my server to my app, I get successfull message:

{"multicast_id":*SOME_ID*,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:*SOME_ID*"}]}

But my app does not show any notifcation or alert. I've been trying more than 6 different guides on the web and still couldn't find a way to recieve this notifications from my app.

How to recieve this notification and show them in my app as push notification even when the user without the application on?

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("New Message!");
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

Broadcast Receiver

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably the push is being sent to your app, but you're not handling it properly. If you don't share some of your app's code, I can't infer anything else. Do you have the proper permissions added to your manifest?

Comment: please post the code you are using for your IntentService

Comment: Yes, about the permission i'm sure, but I have no idea how to handle the notification I sent. Tried to use everything I found on the web, nothing worked.

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast I posted it, but I have nothing related to it in my main activity

Comment: Please add the code for your BroadcastReceiver as well

Comment: The `IntentService` is running on a background `Thread`. I do not remember if you can `notify()` outside the UI `Thread`. Use a `Handler` to `post()` and see if it works.

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast Code added. Emmanuel, its running autmically and no need to declare something in the mainactivity? seem great.

Comment: I did not get your last comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");

    // showing an alert activity if there is an active activity 

    Intent pushReceivedIntent = new Intent("Push");
    pushReceivedIntent.putExtras(data);

    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
    if(componentInfo.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.APP_PACKAGE)){
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(pushReceivedIntent);
    }
    else{
        // showNotification(data);
    }
}
```

and...

```
private void showNotification(Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

This is the Intent Service I use,

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
private static final String gcm_defaultSenderId = "1234556";

public RegistrationIntentService() {
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    try {
        // [START register_for_gcm]
        // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls
        // are local.
        // [START get_token]
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        String token = instanceID.getToken(gcm_defaultSenderId,
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
        // [END get_token]


        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(token);

        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER", true).apply();
        // [END register_for_gcm]
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
        // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
        // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER", false).apply();
    }
    // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
    Intent registrationComplete = new Intent("REGISTRATION_COMPLETE");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    Log.d("token ", token);
    //TODO: Send This to server
}
```

}

Now, In your activities onResume Method, u need to add the receiver.

```
 protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // receiver to get the Notification ALert
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("PUSH");

    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
            intent1.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    // Push Notification receiver
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("REGISTRATION_COMPLETE"));
}
```

Also, check the device tokens as well.

Comment: `Constants.ACTION_PUSH` What is it? I have an error with this Constants class, I don't have it.

Comment: @user4177344: Sorry, my bad. That was a constant used to identify the intent. Have edited my answer. Thanks for point it out.

Comment: Fine, but what I'm doing with it? Just adding this code as a new java class or what? How do I implement it to show me the push I've sent from my php code? I still get no notifications

Comment: did u follow this properly? https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start. Works fine for me. I can share my complete implementaion if u want.